# Insert date in specific format into MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I need to insert the current date in the following format into a TIMESTAMP column in a MySQL db: `d-m-Y`

As of now I am using SQL `NOW()`, which returns the date  as `Y-m-d`. Because I am using AJAX to display the data I cannot format the returned result using `$date_returned->format(d-m-Y)`. Therefore I need to insert the date in the format that I will display on my AJAX call.

I tried to insert the date using the following functions:

```
 1) date('d-m-Y');    
 2) (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');
```

I understand these two functions do pretty much the same thing but I was not sure what else I should try.

MySQL threw the following error for both dates:

```
Error : (1292) Incorrect datetime value: '-2014' for column 'msg_date' at row 1
```

I am guessing this should be an easy fix but I can't figure out what is wrong.
I tried both `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` on MySQL's end but neither worked. (I need it to be `TIMESTAMP` though).

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(yourdate))`?

Comment: Show your query after the PHP variables have been interpolated.

Comment: store it as a varchar...

Answer (score 1):

```
$newdate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('10-09-2015'));
```

or if you want current time just use

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `msg_date` column's structure is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, the date format should be:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

which can be formatted through PHP like this:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Or if you already have a date, and you want it to convert to that format, we can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
```

For more date format, check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL error message indicated that you had the date format the wrong way around.

Year must go first, then month, then day, as in:

```
date('Y-m-d')  // right
```

In your first example, you have

```
date('d-m-Y')  // wrong
```

In one of your examples above, you have it right, but you say you got the same response, so I assume that was not what you actually tried.

Another thing to note is that a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` column stores both a date and time.  It's valid to give MySQL just a date (MySQL will just leave the time at zero), but if you have no need to store a time, you may as well make the column `DATE` instead of `TIMESTAMP`.

If you want to display your dates as `d-m-Y` then by all means do so, but they need to be sent to MySQL as `Y-m-d`.